# How do I migrate a Launchpad project to GitHub including the Bug/Issues?

Tags: github, launchpad

Migrating the code from Launchpad (bzr) to GitHub (git) is not the big problem.
But is there a way to migrate the bugs/tickets from a Launchpad project to a GitHub one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project called [LP2GH](http://lp2gh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/moving_issues.html?highlight=import) ("Launchpad to GitHub"), which can do that. The link above leads you to a documentation about moving your issues.

> This document will give you a detailed account of how to transfer your bugs, blueprints and milestones from Launchpad to GitHub and explain what to do once you’ve moved.

There is another project called [github-issue-importer](https://github.com/johnf/github-issue-importer), which is aimed exactly at this task. It seems easier to use then the first one.

> Github Issue Importer imports bugs into github issues. Currently it only supports Launchpad. It is hoped it will support other bug trackers in the future.
>
> The importer will import each bug and it's comments into github.

Comment: PS: They showed up after a quick google of [`launchpad to github issues`](http://google.com/search?q=launchpad+to+github+issues), a simple google would have saved you some time.

Comment: I used different keywords and a different (better) search-engine without real success. e.g. "Issue" is a GitHub word not used in Launchpad, ... Searching for that is not so easy for a foreign as you think. Please stop to think each "stupid" queustion on Stackoverflow is the result of a lazy person who didn't used a search engine before. Of course I did!

Comment: @buhtz I am foreign as well and your question is not stupid **at all**. I just added what I searched for, maybe someone comes here 5 years later and is lost as well, because these two projects are outdated by then and he needs a updated solution. I was happy to answer a good on-topic question with my skills. :)

Comment: Why unaccept the answer? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: I haven't tested the answer yet so I can not accept it.