# Migrate Launchpad bugs to GitHub Issues > trigger abuse detection

Tags: github, github-api, launchpad

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728943/1139841) I'm trying to migrate my project bugs from Launchpad to GitHub. With both tools [LP2GH](http://lp2gh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/moving_issues.html?highlight=import) and [github-issue-importer](https://github.com/johnf/github-issue-importer) I'm running into an `abuse detection trigger`

```
exception: {"message":
               "You have triggered an abuse detection mechanism
                and have been temporarily blocked from content
                creation. Please retry your request again later.",
            "documentation_url":
               "https://developer.github.com/v3#abuse-rate-limits"
           }
```

<sub>This is from LP2GH</sub>

If I wait for a while and retry to migrate they will both start from scratch, create duplicate issues and end up at the same issue as before (again with an abuse trigger).

How can I migrate **all** bugs?

Comment: @ downvoter: hope you had fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a `failsafe` method to `lp2gh` which will retry after a minute. A [pull request](https://github.com/termie/lp2gh/pull/3) is pending.